# How to multiply and divide all values in a vector using a list in R and how to filter a list

Tags: r, list, filter, multiplication, divide

I have a list (of 83 data frames) and would like to multiply one of the variables (i.e. Mn, see 'practice' df below) by 10000, across the entire list. I would then like to find the maximum value of Mn (within each data frame) and then retain this value (the maximum value) and all values below it (within each data frame). Along with these Mn values, I would like to retain the corresponding values from all other variables within the data frames (i.e. Ba, Sr). I want to exclude all values above this point from each data frame, for all variables. Once I have done this reduction I would then like to return the Mn to it's initial values (i.e. divide Mn by 10000).

Below is the practice script and what I would like to achieve (with Mn being multiplied by 10000 beforehand and then divided by 10000 afterwards). Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Ba <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
Sr <- c(1,1,1,2,2)
Mn <- c(1,1,2,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Ba, Sr, Mn)

df

#   Ba Sr Mn
# 1  1  1  1
# 2  1  1  1
# 3  1  1  2
# 4  2  2  1
# 5  2  2  1
```

This is what I want to achieve in R:

```
Ba <- c(1,2,2)
Sr <- c(1,2,2)
Mn <- c(2,1,1)
df <- data.frame(Ba, Sr, Mn)

df

#     Ba  Sr  Mn
# 1   1   1   2
# 2   2   2   1
# 3   2   2   1
```

I think the script for the filter part of my question is something like this:

```
MaxMn <- lapply(df, function(df){
  df %>% 
   filter(cummax(invoke(pmax, cur_data())) == max(cur_data()))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select all the rows from the max value in `Mn` column you can use `filter` as -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(row_number() >= which.max(Mn))

#  Ba Sr Mn
#1  1  1  2
#2  2  2  1
#3  2  2  1
```

with `slice` -

```
df %>% slice(which.max(Mn):n())
```

and in base R -

```
df[which.max(Mn):nrow(df), ]
```

---

You can apply this to list of dataframes using `lapply`/`map` -

```
lapply(list_df, function(df) df %>% filter(row_number() >= which.max(Mn)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Do you know how I firstly multiply Mn by 10000, before using the script you provided, and then how to divide it back by 10000 on the reduced data created after using the script you provided?

Comment: You can use `df %>% mutate(Mn = Mn * 10000) %>% filter(row_number() >= which.max(Mn)) %>% mutate(Mn = Mn/10000)` but why would you want to do that? Multiplying by 10000 and dividing by the same gives you the same number.

Comment: I may not need to... The Sr values are much greater than the Mn values in my data, and with the original script I used (with cummax), I wasn't able to get the maximum of Mn as it was much lower in magnitudes of 10000 than Sr. I will run your script now and let you know how I go. Thanks for your help...I am an R rookie!

Comment: My df is named Graphdat, in the first part of the script you have: lapply(list_df, function(df). Does this mean I enter it as lapply(list_Graphdat, function(Graphdat) or just simply: lapply(Graphdat, function(Graphdat) ?

Comment: Also, Mn in my data is actually Mn55:Ca. I have entered your script as:                                                            
MaxMn <-lapply(Graphdat,function(Graphdat){
    Graphdat %>% 
    filter(row_number() >= which.max(Mn55:Ca))
}) 
But I am getting this error Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`. x object 'Mn55' not found i Input `..1` is `row_number() >= which.max(Mn55:Ca)`. Any idea why?

Comment: What is `class(Graphdat)` ? Is `Mn55:Ca` name of one column?

Comment: Yes Mn55:Ca is the name of the column/variable and Graphdat is the df/list. I sorted it out and the script works perfectly when I put the commas in i.e. (`Mn55:Ca`). Thanks again Ronak.